# plotshape not plotting on expected candle

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying plot circle above candle when SMA50 falls between candle low and a low threashold of 1%. I am using code below.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//

//@version=5
_close = close
_low = low
_lowerThreshold = _low - _low * 0.01 // threshold value to determine value near 
indicator("SMA Through Candle", overlay = true)
sma = ta.sma(_close, 50)
//sma just below low
smaNearLow = false
if sma >= _lowerThreshold and sma <= _low
    smaNearLow := true
//
plotshape(series = (smaNearLow == true)? close:na, style = shape.circle, location = location.abovebar, offset = 5)
plot(series = _lowerThreshold, style = plot.style_steplinebr)
```

Below is the result
[image]

As you can see, I have add stepline below 1%  low price, and SMA50 in yellow line. I was expecting circle shape will appear at the right check mark and actual shapes are plotted entirely at wrong  candles. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an offsetin your plotshape call set to 5, so your plot shapes are shifted 5 bars forward - remove the offset and the dots will show over the candles you have your check marks for.

```
plotshape(series = (smaNearLow == true)? close:na, style = shape.circle, location = location.abovebar)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking its the offset of location.abovebar